# Input field is not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form inside which I am having input and dropdown of Bootstrap 4.
I have several input field and their labels, but at one place I want to replace label with input field, but the input field below and the one I am putting are colliding with each other. I want to have space between them.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="categoryCode">Uber Eats</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="subCategoryCode">ABCD1</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="subCategoryCode">ABCD</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the place of ABCD1 I want an input field, which should be separate from the one below.

What I am  doing is at place of label for ABCD1 , I am putting this: `

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

                    </div>
                </div>`
```

but output is not what I am expecting 
[image: It is comming somthing like this which I don't want]

There must be some space between them and should be aligned in the row of other label which are `Uber eats` and `ABCD`

Comment: you want more space between the collumns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `margin` bootstrap classes to achieve it

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/daKPNa`777`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="categoryCode">Uber Eats</label>
      <div class="input-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="subCategoryCode">ABCD</label>
      <div class="input-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dis-alignment occurred previously because you have taken the first label row and 
first input group row into just one "Form Row".
Just separate them into different Form Rows and everything back to as expected.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">

   <!-- Added separate form row for first row which includes labels and one new group -->
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <label for="categoryCode">Uber Eats</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <label for="categoryCode">Uber Eats</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Separated the input groups -->
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```